# User input in main accessed by member functions

Tags: c++, input, return-value, counter, member-functions

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "header8.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Counter test;
    string input;

    cout << "Enter a string\n";
    getline(cin, input);
    test.countcharacters();
    test.countnumbers();
}

void Counter::countcharacters(){
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<input.length(); i++){
        if(input.at(i) == 'a'){
            alphabet[0]++;
        }
    }
}

void Counter::countnumbers(){
    for(unsigned int i;i<input.length();i++){
        if(input.at(i) == '0'){
            numbers[i]++;
        }
    }
}
```

My error:

When I enter my string, the value always returns 0. Any idea why?

Comment: Please indent your code so that it's readable.

Comment: And the four missing braces would be good.

Comment: From what I can tell, `test` has no knowledge at all of `input`. I'd wager that if it compiles, it's using some default string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post your Counter class definition
As one of the comments correctly stated, I can see no way counter sees the same input var.

Edit: then based on your code the fix should be
replace in main

```
getline(cin, input);
```

with

```
getline(cin, test.input);
```

and remove

```
string input;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

```
int main()
{
    string input;
    cout << "Enter a string\n";
    getline(cin, input);

    Counter test(input);  // highlight
    test.countcharacters();
    test.countnumbers();
}
```

You need to call the constructor of class `Counter` and transfer 'input' to `Counter::input` (of course, you need to add a constructor with a string as the parameter). Or you can write a function as below:

```
void Counter::setInput(string _input)
{
    this.input = _input;
}
```

and call this function before you start counting.